# Generic class and interface in c#

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, generic-programming

How can I do this in C#?

```
  public class SomeClass<T extends  SomeInterface>{}
```

This is a generic class of `T`, and `T` must implement the interface `SomeInterface`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) constraint [clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public class SomeClass<T>
   where T : SomeInterface
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

With type constraints:

```
public class SomeClass<T> where T : SomeInterface
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx